# Is casting float to int inside processor in C

Tags: c, optimization, casting, floating-point, x87

I'm interested in how the compiler does to cast a `float` into an `int` by instructions like :

```
    float x_f = 3.1415
    int x = (int)x_f;
```

Especially talking about speed. Is it super-fast like build-in processor instruction? Or does it need computing?

I also wander if it changes something if the `float` always contains an exact integer (ex: `x_f = 3.0000`).

EDIT: This question is for gcc compilers used on intel x86 processors.

EDIT2: Does it change something if `x_f = 3.0` ?

Comment: The answer obviously depends from the target architecture...

Comment: indeed, it is an intel x86 processor

Comment: Then it still depends. Will it be using x87 instructions or SSE?

Comment: @MatteoItalia: I am realy interested in cases where the `float` is actually an integer.

Comment: The question this one was marked as a duplicate of was for C++. Because C and C++ are different languages, I'm voting to reopen.

Comment: Seconded. The question and answers in the linked "duplicate" question are highly C++-flavored.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It depends a lot on the particular cpu. Since you're interested in x86, the original 387 fpu has an instruction to convert float to integer, but it can't be used directly because it uses the default rounding mode, whereas conversions in C are required to truncate, not round. Thus, the following function:

```
int f(float x)
{
    return x;
}
```

compiles to (with `gcc -O3 -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables`, to avoid crud in the asm):

```
        .text
        .p2align 4,,15
        .globl  f
        .type   f, @function
f:
        subl    $8, %esp
        fnstcw  6(%esp)
        movw    6(%esp), %ax
        movb    $12, %ah
        movw    %ax, 4(%esp)
        flds    12(%esp)
        fldcw   4(%esp)
        fistpl  (%esp)
        fldcw   6(%esp)
        movl    (%esp), %eax
        addl    $8, %esp
        ret
```

What it's doing it saving, changing, and restoring the fpu control word to change the rounding mode.

On the other hand, if you're building for a target that has SSE available for floating point, you get:

```
        .text
        .globl  f
        .type   f, @function
f:
        cvttss2si       4(%esp), %eax
        ret
```

So, it **really** depends.

Finally, since you mentioned you're particularly interested in the case where the value is already a whole number, this does not make any difference. The cpu operations to convert almost surely don't care. However, in this case **you** can cheat: since you know the input is a whole number, rounding and truncation produce the same result, and you can use `lrintf` rather than casting or implicitly converting to float. This should be a major improvement on x86 targets not using sse for math, especially if the compiler recognizes `lrintf` and inlines it. Here is the same function, using `lrintf(x)` instead of `x`, with the `-fno-math-errno` option added (otherwise gcc assumes libm might want to set `errno` and thus doesn't replace the call):

```
f:
        pushl   %eax
        flds    8(%esp)
        fistpl  (%esp)
        movl    (%esp), %eax
        popl    %edx
        ret
```

Note that gcc did a bad job of compiling this function; it could have generated:

```
f:
        flds    4(%esp)
        fistpl  4(%esp)
        movl    4(%esp), %eax
        ret
```

This is valid because the argument space on the stack belongs to the callee and may be clobbered at will. And even if it weren't, `movl (%esp),%eax ; popl %edx` when you don't care what ends up in `edx` is an idiotic way of writing `popl %eax`...

Comment: Given that SSE is nearly 15 years old, it’s pretty safe to assume that such conversions are fast unless you know you’re dealing with “exotic” legacy compilers/hardware.

Comment: Will GCC ever use `fisttp`, by the way?

Comment: @harold: yes, for conversions to int64 when building 32-bit, and for conversions from long double.

Comment: @StephenCanon: SSE is not part of the normal/default x86 ABI, however. You have to compile with non-default `-march` and/or `-mfpmath=sse` with `-msse2` to get gcc to generate it.

Comment: @harold: `fisttp` is an SSE3 instruction so it can only be used on targets with SSE3.

Comment: I know, I was just wondering whether GCC would actually go ahead and use it (when allowed to).

Comment: @EricPostpischil: I consider instruction set part of the ABI since it affects whether a given binary can run on a given cpu/kernel. If a binary is using SSE2 instructions, it cannot run on pre-SSE2 hardware unless the kernel emulates SSE2 instructions. I agree it's a *different aspect* of ABI however -- one which does not affect linkage between compiled translation units, but rather the interface between the application and the hardware and/or kernel.

Comment: @harold: For the record, yes, if `fisttp` is available, GCC uses it. https://godbolt.org/z/x8MnzGdaj . Even if that means pessimizing cases like this where the float is in memory, not an x87 reg, where GCC uses `cvttss2si  eax, DWORD PTR [esp+4]` / `ret` with `-msse2` without `-msse3`.  (If we use `-mfpmath=sse` instead of the default `-mfpmath=387`, GCC won't be tempted to fld / fisttp / integer-reload.)  It is of course a win when in the more common case where the FP value is the result of a calculation.

Answer (score 2):

Of course, it can be super-fast if the processor you're building for has a super-fast way of doing it. C doesn't require processors to have such instructions, so it will depend on the compiler and processor you're building for.

In other words, "it depends".